# creating a hhmmss template with xslt from MediaInfo XML output

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to output a consistent hh:mm:ss tag from the duration tag generated by MediaInfo's XML.  But I'm not sure how to create an xsl:template that will format the duration the way I'd like. MediaInfo outputs the duration of an audio file for me in two ways, for example:

```
<MediaInfoDuration>1h 58mn</MediaInfoDuration>
```

which I'd like to translate to

```
<Duration>01:58:00</Duration>
```

and

```
<MediaInfoDuration>56mn 48s</MediaInfoDuration>
```

which I'd like to translate to

```
<Duration>00:56:48</Duration>
```

The only thing I really know how to do is use substrings, but since the "mn" can appear in different positions and the "s" sometimes not at all, I'm not sure how to do it.  I think I need to employee variables and maybe xsl:choose, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it. I've assumed, given your example, that elements containing 'h' will never also contain 's'.

This XSLT stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <!-- The identity transform. -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match MediaInfoDuration elements containing 'h'. -->
  <xsl:template match="MediaInfoDuration[contains(., 'h')]">
    <Duration>
      <xsl:call-template name="hh-mm-ss">
        <xsl:with-param name="hours" select="substring-before(., 'h')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="minutes" select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'h '), 'mn')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Duration>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Match the other kind of MediaInfoDuration element. -->
  <xsl:template match="MediaInfoDuration">
    <Duration>
      <xsl:call-template name="hh-mm-ss">
        <xsl:with-param name="minutes" select="substring-before(., 'mn')" />
        <xsl:with-param name="seconds" select="substring-before(substring-after(., 'mn '), 's')"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
    </Duration>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Formatting the output. -->
  <xsl:template name="hh-mm-ss">
    <xsl:param name="hours" select=" '0' "/>
    <xsl:param name="minutes" select=" '0' " />
    <xsl:param name="seconds" select=" '0' "/>

    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($hours, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($minutes, '00')"/>
    <xsl:text>:</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="format-number($seconds, '00')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when applied to this input XML:

```
<root>
  <MediaInfoDuration>56mn 48s</MediaInfoDuration> 
  <MediaInfoDuration>1h 58mn</MediaInfoDuration> 
</root>
```

produces this output:

```
<root>
  <Duration>00:56:48</Duration> 
  <Duration>01:58:00</Duration> 
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works well, although I'm not sure how to fit it into my existing XSL.  I guess I over simplified it and now I'm not sure where exactly to paste it. Here's the document I'm transforming.

```
<File>
<track type="General">
<Complete_name>F:\NYAC\WNYC-NYAC-2002-06-06-24719-B.wav</Complete_name>
<Format>Wave</Format>
<File_size>573 MiB</File_size>
<MediaInfoDuration>56mn 48s</MediaInfoDuration>
<Overall_bit_rate_mode>Constant</Overall_bit_rate_mode>
<Overall_bit_rate>1 411 Kbps</Overall_bit_rate>
<Album>Album 020D5001</Album>
<Part_Position>0</Part_Position>
<Part_Total>0</Part_Total>
<Genre>Unknown / Unknown</Genre>
<Released_date>0000</Released_date>
<Recorded_date>0000 / 0000</Recorded_date>
<Original_source_form_Name>Album 020D5001</Original_source_form_Name>
<MCDI>Yes</MCDI>
</track>

<track type="Audio">
<Format>PCM</Format>
<Format_settings__Endianness>Little</Format_settings__Endianness>
<Format_settings__Sign>Signed</Format_settings__Sign>
<Codec_ID>1</Codec_ID>
<Duration>56mn 48s</Duration>
<Bit_rate_mode>Constant</Bit_rate_mode>
<Bit_rate>1 411.2 Kbps</Bit_rate>
<Channel_s_>2 channels</Channel_s_>
<Sampling_rate>44.1 KHz</Sampling_rate>
<Bit_depth>16 bits</Bit_depth>
<Stream_size>573 MiB (100%)</Stream_size>
</track>
```

And here is my current xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:mt="http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/" xmlns:la="http://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/" xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings" extension-element-prefixes="str" xmlns="http://www.pbcore.org/PBCore/PBCoreNamespace.html" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" version="1.0" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="Mediainfo">
    <pbcoreCollection>
    </pbcoreCollection>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="File">
        <pbcoreCollection>
            <pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
        <xsl:variable name="mediainfoSource">MediaInfoLib</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="mediainfoVersion"><xsl:value-of select="../@version"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:for-each select="track[@type='General']">
            <!-- pbcoreTitle/pbcoreTitleType -->
            <pbcoreTitle titleType="Collection">WNYC</pbcoreTitle>
            <!-- pbcoreIdentifier/pbcoreIdentifierSource -->
            <xsl:if test="Complete_name">
                <pbcoreIdentifier>
                    <xsl:attribute name="source">WNYC Archive Catalog</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(Complete_name,30,5)"/>
                </pbcoreIdentifier>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- instantiationIdentifier/instantiationIdentifierSource -->
            <pbcoreInstantiation>
            <xsl:if test="Complete_name">
                <instantiationIdentifier>
                    <xsl:attribute name="source">David Title</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(Complete_name,9,26)"/>
                </instantiationIdentifier>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- dates -->
            <xsl:if test="Complete_name">
                <instantiationDate>
                    <xsl:attribute name="dateType">Broadcast</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(Complete_name,19,10)"/>
                </instantiationDate>
            </xsl:if>

                <instantiationDate>
                    <xsl:attribute name="dateType">Created</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:text>2013-09-14</xsl:text>
                </instantiationDate>


            <!-- formatDigital -->
            <instantiationDigital><xsl:text>BWF</xsl:text></instantiationDigital>

            <!-- formatLocation -->
            <instantiationLocation>DAVID</instantiationLocation>

            <!-- formatMediaType -->
            <instantiationMediaType>Sound</instantiationMediaType>

            <!-- formatGenerations -->
            <instantiationGenerations>Master: preservation</instantiationGenerations>

            <!-- formatFileSize -->
            <xsl:if test="File_size"><!-- this expresses filesize as an integer count of bytes -->
                <instantiationFileSize>
                    <xsl:attribute name="unitsOfMeasure">bytes</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(File_size)"/>
                </instantiationFileSize>
            </xsl:if>

            <!-- formatChannelConfiguration -->
            <instantiationChannelConfiguration><xsl:text>Stereo</xsl:text></instantiationChannelConfiguration>

            <!-- language -->
                <instantiationLanguage><xsl:text>eng</xsl:text></instantiationLanguage>         
            <instantiationEssenceTrack>
                <essenceTrackType>audio</essenceTrackType>
                <essenceTrackIdentifier>
                    <xsl:attribute name="source">David Title</xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:value-of select="substring(Complete_name,9,26)"/>
                </essenceTrackIdentifier>
                <essenceTrackStandard>Linear PCM</essenceTrackStandard>
                <essenceTrackEncoding>Captured from CD via MF Digital Ripstation</essenceTrackEncoding>
                <essenceTrackSamplingRate>44.1 kHz</essenceTrackSamplingRate>
                <essenceTrackBitDepth>16</essenceTrackBitDepth>

                </xsl:if>
            </instantiationEssenceTrack>
            </pbcoreInstantiation>
            </xsl:for-each>
            </pbcoreDescriptionDocument>
            </pbcoreCollection>
</xsl:template>
```